# R plotly stacked bar chart with patterns

Tags: r, plotly, stack, bar-chart, shapes

I have a `data.frame` which I'd like to plot as a stacked bar chart with `R`'s `plotly`:

```
data.df <- data.frame(group = c(rep("g1",6),rep("g2",6),rep("g3",6)),
                 sample = rep(c(paste0("f", 1:3), paste0("m", 1:3)), 3),
                 f = rep(100/6, 6))
```

Each of the `data.df$group` is a bar where the `data.df$sample` are the layers in the stack in each bar (with a different color), and since there are two sets of `data.df$sample` I'd like each one to have its own pattern.

Here's the `data.frame` with the colors and patterns:

```
colors.df <- data.frame(sample = c(c(paste0("f", 1:3)), c(paste0("m", 1:3))),
                        color = rep(c("#FFC0CB", "#FFFF00", "#00FFFF"),2),
                        shape = c(rep("stripe", 3),rep("cross", 3)))
```

Here's the `plotly` code I'm trying:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(x = data.df$group, y = data.df$f, name = data.df$sample, color = data.df$sample,
        type = 'bar', colors = colors.df$color, marker = list(pattern = list(shape = colors.df$chape))) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(showticklabels = F), yaxis = list(title = "%", zeroline = F), barmode = 'stack', orientation = 'v')
```

Which ignores the `markers` argument and gives:

[image]

Any idea how to get the two sets in `data.df$sample` to come out in different patterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the spelling of the shape and define the pattern as a symbol and not a string:

```r
data.df <- data.frame(group = c(rep("g1",6),rep("g2",6),rep("g3",6)),
                      sample = rep(c(paste0("f", 1:3), paste0("m", 1:3)), 3),
                      shape = c(rep("x", 3),rep("|", 3)), ## I added the shape in data.df
                      f = rep(100/6, 6))

colors.df <- data.frame(sample = c(c(paste0("f", 1:3)), c(paste0("m", 1:3))),
                        color = rep(c("#FFC0CB", "#FFFF00", "#00FFFF"),2))
```

Then plot:

```r
library(plotly)
plot_ly(x = data.df$group, y = data.df$f, name = data.df$sample, color = data.df$sample,
        type = 'bar', colors = colors.df$color, marker = list(pattern = list(shape = data.df$shape))) %>% ## Here, shape was misspelled from your original code
  layout(xaxis = list(showticklabels = F), yaxis = list(title = "%", zeroline = F), barmode = 'stack')
```

[image]