# Color and pattern coded stacked bar chart in R plotly

Tags: r, plotly, stacked-bar-chart

This is an expansion to [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77012974/r-plotly-stacked-bar-chart-with-patterns):
I have compositional data that I want to plot as a stacked bar chart using `R`'s `plotly`:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
data.df <- data.frame(cluster = c(rep("c1", 8), rep("c2", 8), rep("c3", 8), rep("c4", 8)),
                      y.val = sample(1:10, 32, replace = T),
                      age = rep(c(rep("y", 2), rep("o", 2)), 8),
                      compartment = rep(c(rep("a", 4), rep("b", 4)), 4),
                      subject = rep(c("y_1", "y_2", "o_1", "o_2"), 8),
                      age_compartment_subject = rep(c("y_a_1", "y_a_2", "o_a_1", "o_a_2", "y_b_1", "y_b_2", "o_b_1", "o_b_2"), 4),
                      age_compartment = c(rep("y_a", 2), rep("o_a", 2), rep("y_b", 2), rep("o_b", 2)),
                      color = c(rep("#B2182B", 2), rep("#FDDBC7", 2), rep("#2166AC", 2), rep("#D1E5F0", 2)),
                      shape = rep(c("+", "-", "x", "."), 8)) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(cluster, compartment) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(y.val = 100*y.val/sum(y.val)) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

1. `df$cluster` correspond to the bars
2. `df$y.val` are the values corresponding to the bar stacks
3. `df$subject` are subjects from which the `df$y.val`'s were drawn where they sum up to 100% per each `df$cluster` and `df$compartment`
4. `df$age` are the age groups of the subjects
5. `df$compartment` are two compartments from which each sample was drawn

I want to present each `df$cluster` as a bar where the stacked sectors are color-coded according to `df$age_compartment` and pattern-coded according to `df$subject`.

Setting `df$cluster`, `df$subject`, `df$age_compartment_subject`, and `data.df$age_compartment` as factors for getting the desired order:

```
data.df$cluster <- factor(data.df$cluster, levels = c("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"))
data.df$subject <- factor(data.df$subject, levels = c("y_1", "y_2", "o_1", "o_2"))
data.df$age_compartment_subject <- factor(data.df$age_compartment_subject, levels = c("y_a_1", "y_a_2", "o_a_1", "o_a_2", "y_b_1", "y_b_2", "o_b_1", "o_b_2"))
data.df$age_compartment <- factor(data.df$age_compartment, levels = c("y_a", "y_b", "o_a", "o_b"))
```

And defining `data.frame`'s for colors and pattern shapes:

```
colors.df <- data.frame(color.group = levels(data.df$age_compartment), color = c("#B2182B", "#FDDBC7", "#2166AC", "#D1E5F0"))
shapes.df <- data.frame(shape.group = levels(data.df$subject), shape = c("+", "-", "x", "."))
```

Here's my `plotly` command:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(x = data.df$cluster, y = data.df$y.val, name = data.df$age_compartment_subject, color = data.df$age_compartment,
        type = 'bar', colors = colors.df$color, marker = list(pattern = list(shape = data.df$shape))) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = "%", zeroline = F), barmode = 'stack')
```

Which gives:
[image]

I was hoping to get each bar with 8 stacks according to `data.df$age_compartment_subject` levels, shaped by `data.df$subject` (`data.df$shape`), and colored by `df$age_compartment` but it doesn't come out that way.

Any idea how to fix it?

Writing out the `plotly` function with each bar stack as a separate trace:

```
plotly::plot_ly(x = dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "y_a_1")$cluster,
                y = dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "y_a_1")$y.val,
                type = 'bar', name = 'y_a_1',
                marker = list(color = unique(dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "y_a_1")$color),
                              pattern = list(shape=unique(dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "y_a_1")$shape)))) %>%
  plotly::add_trace(x = dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "y_a_2")$cluster,
                    y = dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "y_a_2")$y.val,
                    type = 'bar', name = 'y_a_2',
                    marker = list(color = unique(dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "y_a_2")$color),
                                  pattern = list(shape=unique(dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "y_a_2")$shape)))) %>%   
  plotly::add_trace(x = dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "o_a_1")$cluster,
                    y = dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "o_a_1")$y.val,
                    type = 'bar', name = 'o_a_1',
                    marker = list(color = unique(dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "o_a_1")$color),
                                  pattern = list(shape=unique(dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "o_a_1")$shape)))) %>%   
  plotly::add_trace(x = dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "o_a_2")$cluster,
                    y = dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "o_a_2")$y.val,
                    type = 'bar', name = 'o_a_2',
                    marker = list(color = unique(dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "o_a_2")$color),
                                  pattern = list(shape=unique(dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "o_a_2")$shape)))) %>%   
  plotly::add_trace(x = dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "y_b_1")$cluster,
                    y = dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "y_b_1")$y.val,
                    type = 'bar', name = 'y_b_1',
                    marker = list(color = unique(dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "y_b_1")$color),
                                  pattern = list(shape=unique(dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "y_b_1")$shape)))) %>%   
  plotly::add_trace(x = dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "y_b_2")$cluster,
                    y = dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "y_b_2")$y.val,
                    type = 'bar', name = 'y_b_2',
                    marker = list(color = unique(dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "y_b_2")$color),
                                  pattern = list(shape=unique(dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "y_b_2")$shape)))) %>%   
  plotly::add_trace(x = dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "o_b_1")$cluster,
                    y = dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "o_b_1")$y.val,
                    type = 'bar', name = 'o_b_1',
                    marker = list(color = unique(dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "o_b_1")$color),
                                  pattern = list(shape=unique(dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "o_b_1")$shape)))) %>%   
  plotly::add_trace(x = dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "o_b_2")$cluster,
                    y = dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "o_b_2")$y.val,
                    type = 'bar', name = 'o_b_2',
                    marker = list(color = unique(dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "o_b_2")$color),
                                  pattern = list(shape=unique(dplyr::filter(data.df,age_compartment_subject == "o_b_2")$shape)))) %>%   
  plotly::layout(yaxis = list(title = '%'),barmode = 'stack')
```

Does produce the desired results:
[image]

But becomes long and impractical for data with many stack groups, so I was hoping for a concise `plotly` function.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the traces one by one, you could split your data to avoid the filtering and use `Reduce` (but I guess a `for` loop will also do) to add the single traces:

```
library(plotly)

data.df_split <- data.df |>
  split(~age_compartment_subject)

plot_ly(x = ~cluster, y = ~y.val) |>
  Reduce(
    \(p, x) {
      plotly::add_trace(p,
        data = x,
        type = "bar",
        name = unique(x$age_compartment_subject),
        marker = list(
          color = unique(x$color),
          pattern = list(shape = unique(x$shape))
        )
      )
    },
    x = data.df_split, init = _
  ) |>
  layout(
    yaxis = list(title = "%", zeroline = FALSE),
    barmode = "stack"
  )
```

[image]